# Multi Options Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an action bar in my application with one button that should be options button.
When you click it, it should open few options.
I made a String-Array in the Strings.xml file but I can't get it to work.
Any code samples?
I searched the internet but couldn't find anything.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vogella provides good tutorials. Here is the ActionBar tutorial which shows how to do that: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Make sure you have an xml document in your menu folder in resources called something like mainmenu.xml which should look like the following:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Settings">
</item>

</menu>
```

Then make sure you have the following functions in your Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
// action with ID action_refresh was selected
case R.id.action_refresh:
  Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
  break;
// action with ID action_settings was selected
case R.id.action_settings:
  Toast.makeText(this, "Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
  break;
default:
  break;
}

return true;
  }
```

Comment: No problem. If it works for you and you think it was a good answer, please accept the answer using the tick button. Thanks.